# ANTLR4 grammar token recognition error after import

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am using a [parser grammar](https://github.com/teverett/phpGrammar/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/com/khubla/phpGrammar/PHPParser.g4) and a [lexer grammar](https://github.com/teverett/phpGrammar/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/com/khubla/phpGrammar/PHPLexer.g4) for antlr4 from GitHub to parse PHP in Python3.

When I use these grammars directly my PoC code works:

antlr-test.py

```
from antlr4 import *
# from PHPParentLexer import PHPParentLexer
# from PHPParentParser import PHPParentParser
# from PHPParentParser import PHPParentListener

from PHPLexer import PHPLexer as PHPParentLexer
from PHPParser import PHPParser as PHPParentParser
from PHPParser import PHPParserListener as PHPParentListener


class PhpGrammarListener(PHPParentListener):
    def enterFunctionInvocation(self, ctx):
        print("enterFunctionInvocation " + ctx.getText())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scanner_input = FileStream('test.php')
    lexer = PHPParentLexer(scanner_input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = PHPParentParser(stream)
    tree = parser.htmlDocument()
    walker = ParseTreeWalker()
    printer = PhpGrammarListener()
    walker.walk(printer, tree)
```

which gives the output

```
/opt/local/bin/python3.4 /Users/d/PycharmProjects/name/antlr-test.py
enterFunctionInvocation echo("hi") 
enterFunctionInvocation another_method("String")
enterFunctionInvocation print("print statement")

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I use the following PHPParent.g4 grammar, I get a lot of errors:

```
grammar PHPParent;
options { tokenVocab=PHPLexer; }
import PHPParser;
```

After swapping comments on pythons imports, I get this error

```
/opt/local/bin/python3.4 /Users/d/PycharmProjects/name/antlr-test.py
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '?'
line 1:2 token recognition error at: 'p'
line 1:3 token recognition error at: 'h'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'p'
line 1:5 token recognition error at: '\n'
...
line 2:8 no viable alternative at input '<('
line 2:14 mismatched input ';' expecting {<EOF>, '<', '{', '}', ')', '?>', 'list', 'global', 'continue', 'return', 'class', 'do', 'switch', 'function', 'break', 'if', 'for', 'foreach', 'while', 'new', 'clone', '&', '!', '-', '~', '@', '$', <INVALID>, 'Interface', 'abstract', 'static', Array, RequireOperator, DecimalNumber, HexNumber, OctalNumber, Float, Boolean, SingleQuotedString, DoubleQuotedString_Start, Identifier, IncrementOperator}
line 3:28 mismatched input ';' expecting {<EOF>, '<', '{', '}', ')', '?>', 'list', 'global', 'continue', 'return', 'class', 'do', 'switch', 'function', 'break', 'if', 'for', 'foreach', 'while', 'new', 'clone', '&', '!', '-', '~', '@', '$', <INVALID>, 'Interface', 'abstract', 'static', Array, RequireOperator, DecimalNumber, HexNumber, OctalNumber, Float, Boolean, SingleQuotedString, DoubleQuotedString_Start, Identifier, IncrementOperator}
line 4:28 mismatched input ';' expecting {<EOF>, '<', '{', '}', ')', '?>', 'list', 'global', 'continue', 'return', 'class', 'do', 'switch', 'function', 'break', 'if', 'for', 'foreach', 'while', 'new', 'clone', '&', '!', '-', '~', '@', '$', <INVALID>, 'Interface', 'abstract', 'static', Array, RequireOperator, DecimalNumber, HexNumber, OctalNumber, Float, Boolean, SingleQuotedString, DoubleQuotedString_Start, Identifier, IncrementOperator}
```

However I get no errors when running the antlr4 tool over the grammars. I'm stumped here - what could be causing this issue?

```
$ a4p PHPLexer.g4
warning(146): PHPLexer.g4:363:0: non-fragment lexer rule DoubleQuotedStringBody can match the empty string
$ a4p PHPParser.g4
warning(154): PHPParser.g4:523:0: rule doubleQuotedString contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
$ a4p PHPParent.g4
warning(154): PHPParent.g4:523:0: rule doubleQuotedString contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
```

Comment: Does your Grammar PHPParent only consist of three lines? If not: Complete the grammar.

Comment: It does - I wanted to test importing grammars in isolation.

Comment: Yet, I can only say that java does not allow a grammar without rules. I added a pseudo rule: `myfile : file;` and it compiled (and calling myfile instead of file on the parser object). Yet I did not test the parser, because I do not have a python environment. Have you tried it using such a delegator rule?

Comment: Thanks - I hope to give this a try tomorrow. I'll update you whether it works; if it does make this an answer & I'll accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still erroring out - "mismatched input '<?php echo('hi') ?>' expecting <INVALID>"

Comment: Try to import the Lexer. The error message `line 1:1 token recognition error at:` comes from the lexer and  means that their is no matching lexer rule. From your post I cannot see what contents are in the PHPParentLexer, perhaps the problems lies there.

Comment: This [old post](http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2008-August/029779.html) on the antlr mailing list may be of use?  It mentions that to use the `tokenVocab` option, you need to have a tokens file in the same directory as the grammar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import is ANTLR4 is kind of messy.

First, `tokenVocab` can not generate the lexer you need. It just means that this grammar is using the tokens of `PHPLexer`. If you delete `PHPLexer.tokens`, it won't even compile!

Take a look at `PHPParser.g4` where we also use `options { tokenVocab=PHPLexer; }`. Yet in the python script we still need to use lexer from `PHPLexer` to make it work. Well, this `PHPParentLexer` is not useable at all. That's why you got all the error.

To generate a new lexer out of combined grammar, you need to import it like this:

```
grammar PHPParent;
import PHPLexer;
```

However, `mode` is not supported when importing. `PHPLexer` itself uses `mode` a lot. So it's also not an option.

Can we simply replace `PHPParentLexer` with `PHPLexer`? Sadly, no. Because `PHPParentParser` is generated with `PHPParentLexer`, they are tightly coupled and can not be used seperatly. If you use `PHPLexer`, `PHPParentParser` also won't work. As for this grammar, thanks to the error recovery, it actually works, but gives some error.

There seems to be no better way but to rewrite some of the grammar. There are definitely some design issues in this `import` part of ANTLR4.